# A polymer modal paper-dialog - how to prevent the rest of the interface going dark?

Tags: polymer

When a Polymer (1.0) modal paper-dialog is opened, the background (is that the "withbackdrop"?) goes dark. I want to prevent that, and keep it bright.

I've tried

```
'<paper-dialog id='idTourDialog' modal with-backdrop="false"'
```

My dialog controls a tour of my app, so end-users need to see what it's doing.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `with-backdrop` altogether.

Eg. `<paper-dialog id="tourDialog" modal></paper-dialog>`

Recommended read: [Polymer property binding - reflect to attribute part.](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html)

Note that the with-backdrop property is of boolean type.

Comment: Hi, thanks. With modal set, with-backdrop is defaulted to true. I want to set it false. I removed the quotes from"false" of course. But to confirm, "with-backdrop" is the appropriate property to set anyway? Cheers,s

Comment: Answered part of my question. Without "modal",if I have "with-backdrop" = to true or false, I get a dark background. Remove "with-backdrop" altogether, as you said, and the background stays bright. So it is the correct property (just acknowledging to myself there!). I just need to set it to false in a modal dialog.

Comment: Well, if you check the component page for paper-dialog, this is the description for the modal attribute: "If modal is true, this implies no-cancel-on-outside-click, no-cancel-on-esc-key and with-backdrop." So based on this I assume  you could add the two "no-cancel" attributes explicitly (without adding modal) and you get to your desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a function:

```
List children=dTourDlg.childNodes;
PaperDialog papdlg=children[1];
IronOverlayBackdrop bd=papdlg.backdropElement;
bd.style.display='none';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the modal nature of the dialog, you need the backdrop to prevent the user from clicking through to main page, but you can make it transparent.

The backdrop (an instance of [`iron-overlay-backdrop`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-overlay-behavior?active=iron-overlay-backdrop)) is added to the main document as a child of `body`. To style it, you could define a custom property in the main document like this:

`<style is="custom-style">
  --iron-overlay-backdrop-opacity: 0;
</style>`